# How to convert a complex Java lambda to Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm trying to convert following Java code to Kotlin (interface implementations omitted for readability):

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        validate("some text", extractor -> s -> check(s, extractor));
    }

    private static void validate(String s, Function<Extractor, Validator> factory) {
        final Extractor extractor = all -> all; // use some more meaningful extractor here
        factory.apply(extractor).validate(s);
    }

    private static boolean check(String s, Extractor extractor) {
        return s.equals(extractor.extract(s));
    }

    interface Extractor {
        String extract(String all);
    }

    interface Validator {
        boolean validate(String s);
    }
}
```

This contains a very compact lambda-expression which I would like to translate to Kotlin (for a slightly more readable alternative of the Java lambda, see [1]). My current solution keeps the `interfaces`, but this seems to result in a rather complex call (compare `validate`-invocations in `main`):

```kotlin
object Test {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        validate("test", object : Function<Extractor, Validator> {
            override fun apply(extractor: Extractor): Validator {
                return object : Validator {
                    override fun validate(s: String): Boolean {
                        return check(s, extractor)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun validate(s: String, factory: Function<Extractor, Validator>) {
        val extractor : Extractor = object : Extractor {  // use some more meaningful extractor here
            override fun extract(all: String): String {
                return all
            }
        }
        factory.apply(extractor).validate(s)
    }

    private fun check(s: String, extractor: Extractor): Boolean {
        return s == extractor.extract(s)
    }

    internal interface Extractor {
        fun extract(all: String): String
    }

    internal interface Validator {
        fun validate(s: String): Boolean
    }
}
```

**Question**: when keeping the `interfaces` as is, is there some more efficient `validate`-call?

**Follow-up question**: the logic requires a configurable validation (`Validator`) with complex `check`-methods using configurable extraction (`Extractor`). What would be a more idiomatic design?

[1] The compact lambda corresponds to following more readable code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        validate("some text", extractor -> {
            return s -> {
                return check(s, extractor);
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Function` can already be converted to a lambda. Next, declare `Extractor` and `Validator` as `fun interface`. Then code can finally be rewritten as:

```kotlin
object Test {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        validate("test") { extractor -> Validator { s -> check(s, extractor) } }
    }

    private fun validate(s: String, factory: Function<Extractor, Validator>) {
        val extractor = Extractor { all -> all }   // use some more meaningful extractor here
        factory.apply(extractor).validate(s)
    }

    private fun check(s: String, extractor: Extractor): Boolean {
        return s == extractor.extract(s)
    }

    internal fun interface Extractor {
        fun extract(all: String): String
    }

    internal fun interface Validator {
        fun validate(s: String): Boolean
    }
}
```